Adding labels when chosen selectInput changes pos and neg height of labels
I have an app that has options to show p-value levels as asterisks and confidence intervals as error bars.
When all the observations are positive, it works as intended: the asterisks are positioned just above the column(s) when only the p-value box is selected; or just above the error bar(s) when both the p-value and CI boxes are selected; and in both cases the y-axis limit is extended accordingly if the tallest bar has an asterisk so that it isn't cut off.



This is the layer that does that:
layer_p <- if (input$p_values) {
      column_y_text <- if (input$error_bars) {
        "higher"
      } else {
        "Estimate"
      }
      max_y_text <- table_9_filtered |>
        filter(!is.na(Sig)) |>
        pull(column_y_text) |>
        max()
      list(
        geom_label(
          aes(
            label = Sig,
            y = .data[[column_y_text]],
            group = variable
          ),
          vjust = 0,
          fill = NA,
          label.size = 0,
          label.padding = unit(10, "pt"),
          position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
          na.rm = TRUE
        ),
        if (!is.na(max_y_text))
          expand_limits(y = c(0, max_y_text * 1.1))
      )
    }

However, if the observations are negative, I run into issues:

How can I adjust the layer_p code so that (1) the asterisks go below the columns/error bars when the observations are negative, and (2) the ylimit is extended downwards if the tallest negative bar has an asterisk (i.e. is not NA in the Sig column)?

My code is:
cbPalette <-  c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73")
fun_select_cat <- function(table, cat) {
  table %>%
    filter(variable == cat)
}
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput('cat', 'Select Category', unique(table_9$variable)),
    checkboxInput("p_values", label = p_value_label, value = FALSE),
    checkboxInput("error_bars", label = "Show 95% confidence intervals", value = FALSE)
  ),
  mainPanel(plotOutput('plot_overall'))
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
        
  output$plot_overall <- renderPlot({
    table_9_filtered <- fun_select_cat(table_9, input$cat) |>
      ungroup()
    
    title <- input$cat
      
    layer_error <- if (input$error_bars) {
      lim_lower <- table_9_filtered |>
        pull(lower) |>
        min()
      lim_higher <- table_9_filtered |>
        pull(higher) |>
        max()
      list(
        geom_errorbar(
          aes(ymin = lower,
              ymax = higher),
          width = 0.25,
          position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)
        ),
        if (lim_lower < 0)
          expand_limits(y = c(lim_lower*1.1, lim_higher))
      )
    }
    
    layer_p <- if (input$p_values) {
      column_y_text <- if (input$error_bars) {
        "higher"
      } else {
        "Estimate"
      }
      max_y_text <- table_9_filtered |>
        filter(!is.na(Sig)) |>
        pull(column_y_text) |>
        max()
      list(
        geom_label(
          aes(
            label = Sig,
            y = .data[[column_y_text]],
            group = variable
          ),
          vjust = 0,
          fill = NA,
          label.size = 0,
          label.padding = unit(10, "pt"),
          position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
          na.rm = TRUE
        ),
        if (!is.na(max_y_text))
          expand_limits(y = c(0, max_y_text * 1.1))
      )
    }
    
    table_9_filtered |>
      ggplot(aes(x = Treatment, y = Estimate, fill = Treatment)) +
      geom_col() +
      scale_fill_manual(values = cbPalette) +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = label_comma(), expand = c(0, 0)) +
      theme_classic() +
      scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
      layer_p +
      layer_error +
      labs(title = title, x = NULL, y = NULL)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

dput(table_9):
structure(list(Treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Long Term", 
"Short Term", "Lump Sum"), class = "factor"), variable = c("Anthro. Index", 
"Domestic Violence", "KCPE Score >= 250", "Ladder: Current", 
"Mental Health Depressed (Y/N)", "Years of Schooling", "Anthro. Index", 
"Domestic Violence", "KCPE Score >= 250", "Ladder: Current", 
"Mental Health Depressed (Y/N)", "Years of Schooling", "Anthro. Index", 
"Domestic Violence", "KCPE Score >= 250", "Ladder: Current", 
"Mental Health Depressed (Y/N)", "Years of Schooling"), Estimate = c(0, 
-0.05, 0.04, 0.2, -0.08, -0.09, 0.01, -0.08, 0.08, 0.21, -0.04, 
0.01, 0.07, -0.06, 0, 0.22, -0.07, -0.01), SE = c(0.04, 0.04, 
0.04, 0.07, 0.02, 0.08, 0.04, 0.04, 0.03, 0.06, 0.02, 0.06, 0.04, 
0.04, 0.03, 0.06, 0.02, 0.07), Sig = c(NA, NA, NA, "∗∗∗", 
"∗∗∗", NA, NA, "∗∗", "∗∗∗", "∗∗∗", "∗∗", 
NA, "∗", NA, NA, "∗∗∗", "∗∗∗", NA), lower = c(-0.0784, 
-0.1284, -0.0384, 0.0628, -0.1192, -0.2468, -0.0684, -0.1584, 
0.0212, 0.0924, -0.0792, -0.1076, -0.00839999999999999, -0.1384, 
-0.0588, 0.1024, -0.1092, -0.1472), higher = c(0.0784, 0.0284, 
0.1184, 0.3372, -0.0408, 0.0668, 0.0884, -0.0016, 0.1388, 0.3276, 
-0.000800000000000002, 0.1276, 0.1484, 0.0184, 0.0588, 0.3376, 
-0.0308, 0.1272)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000002877bcd8b80>, sorted = c("Treatment", 
"variable"))


Here is one option to achieve your desired result using an ifelse to conditionally set vjust and which expands the limits to include the range of the data instead of just the max.
layer_p <- if (input$p_values) {
  # Add a helper column to the data
  table_9_filtered$y_text <- if (input$error_bars) {
    ifelse(
      table_9_filtered[["Estimate"]] < 0,
      table_9_filtered[["lower"]],
      table_9_filtered[["higher"]]
    )
  } else {
    table_9_filtered[["Estimate"]]
  }
  
  y_text <- table_9_filtered |>
    filter(!is.na(Sig)) |>
    pull(y_text)
  
  list(
    geom_label(
      aes(
        label = Sig,
        y = y_text,
        group = variable,
        # set vjust conditionally
        vjust = ifelse(
          y_text < 0,
          1,
          0
        ),
      ),
      fill = NA,
      label.size = 0,
      label.padding = unit(10, "pt"),
      position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
      na.rm = TRUE
    ),
    if (any(!is.na(y_text))) {
      # Expand to include the range of the data times 1.1
      expand_limits(y = 1.1 * range(y_text))
    }
  )
}



A request: can you explain please when and why pull is used? E.g., in y_text <- table_9_filtered |>
filter(!is.na(Sig)) |>
pull(y_text)

Aw. Bad notation on my side. In my approach I first add a column with name y_text to the dataset which contains the y position for the label. Then I use pull to get a vector of the label positions for obs. with non-missing Sig which I store in a variable named y_text too. The data column y_text is mapped on y while the variable is used to get the range of y positions.
